# Efficient algorithm for finding period of Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

What is the least time consuming way to find a period of state of irreducible Markov chain? I wondering if there is an algorithm which does not use matrix multiplication?

Comment: You might want to review [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227869/period-of-a-markov-chain-why-is-this-one-aperiodic) and its Answers to make sure the definitions of period of a *state* and period of a Markov chain are clear.  Asking for the "least time consuming way" to do something is a bit subjective, and algorithms that use matrix multiplication might be put in some other terms, such as finding cycles in graphs, that hide the essential operations.

Comment: hardmath, thank you for your response. You are right. I meant period of the state when the chain is irreducible.

Comment: Irreducible case also considered at the reference suggested above by  hardmath

Comment: L.V.Rao, thank you. But "this previous Question" uses matrix multiplication. I need something that does not use it.

Comment: Some of my confusion is from the requirement not to use matrix multiplication.  A (finite) Markov chain is associated with a probability transition matrix.  While this may contain more information than we need to find periods, if you wish to avoid using it, you should say how the information will instead be presented.

Answer (score 0):

There is an efficient algorithm based on breadth-first search here:
[http://cecas.clemson.edu/~shierd/Shier/markov.pdf](http://cecas.clemson.edu/%7Eshierd/Shier/markov.pdf)

Given a dense `N x N` matrix the algorithm would be worst-case `O(n^2)` whereas computing all matrix powers would be `O(n^4)` which is most likely much slower for matrices of any significant size.